# What's the easiest way to average an array of integers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If if have multiple arrays such as

```
[100, 43, 76, 95, 62],
[27, 54, 99, 13, 56],
[56, 92, 01, 46, 87]
```

What is the easiest way to get one array with the average of of each index?
I have a dynamic number of arrays but 6 items in each.

(For example the average for the arrays above would be `[61, 63, 59, 51, 68]`

Comment: We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need one loop that will get the elements for the same index of three arrays and calculate the average:

```js
var arr1 = [100, 43, 76, 95, 62];
var arr2 = [27, 54, 99, 13, 56];
var arr3 = [56, 92, 01, 46, 87];
var res = [];
for(var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
  var avg = Math.round((arr1[i]+ arr2[i]+ arr3[i])/3)
  res.push(avg);
}

console.log(res);
```

And if you have dymanic number of arrays then this works like a charm,

```js
var data = [[100, 43, 76, 95, 62],[27, 54, 99, 13, 56],[56, 92, 01, 46, 87]];
var res = [], sum;
for(var i=0; i<data[0].length; i++){
  sum = 0;
  for(var j=0; j<data.length; j++){
     sum+= data[j][i];
  }
  res.push(Math.round(sum/data.length));
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) one of the sub arrays, and use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) to get the sum of each column. Then divide the sum by the number of sub arrays:

```js
const arr = [
  [100, 43, 76, 95, 62],
  [27, 54, 99, 13, 56],
  [56, 92, 01, 46, 87]
];

const result = arr[0].map((item, index) => 
  Math.round(arr.reduce((avg, sArr) => avg + sArr[index], 0) / arr.length)
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do so in the following way

```js
let arr = [
    [100, 43, 76, 95, 62],
    [27, 54, 99, 13, 56],
    [56, 92, 01, 46, 87]
    ];

let ans = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a.map((x, i) => x+b[i]);
}).map(a => Math.round(a/arr.length));

console.log(ans);
```

Comment: Check my answer, it is what OP wants

Comment: edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

At first your datastructure isnt ideal. May "rotate" the matrix first:

```
 const arr = [
   [100, 43, 76, 95, 62],
   [27, 54, 99, 13, 56],
   [56, 92, 01, 46, 87]
];

const rotated = arr[0].map((_,i)=> arr.map(row=>row[i]));
```

Then you can easily sum up the rows and divide them through their length:

```
const result = rotated.map(
  row => row.reduce((a,b) => a+b ,0)/row.length
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sum all values at the same index and later calculate the average.

```js
var array = [[100, 43, 76, 95, 62], [27, 54, 99, 13, 56], [56, 92, 01, 46, 87]],
    result = array
        .reduce(function (r, a) {
            a.forEach(function (b, i) {
                r[i] = (r[i] || 0) + b;
            });
            return r;
        }, [])
        .map(function (a, i) {
            return Math.round(a / array.length);
        });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `Math.floor`? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Cerbrus, is round better?

Comment: Yea, now the returned values are correct.